# Не получается сделать эффект размытия фона

Tags: css, blur, css-filters

Всем привет. Народ, у кого-нибудь получалось применять размытие Гаусса только к фону определённого блока на странице? Сейчас поясню:

Есть страница, у неё фоновое изображение на всю ширину и на всю высоту. Есть на странице форма. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы у формы фон был прозрачный, но также чтобы только к фону применялось размытие Гаусса, а к элементам формы - нет.

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать? Пока нашёл только css-свойство filter: blur();

Но может можно как то по-другому сделать?

Вот код:  `[https://jsfiddle.net/fenix_63/b6znvjx2/13/][1]`

Вот как хотелось бы видеть: [image: Изображение]

Подскажите, куда копать? А то уже прям и не знаю. backdrop-filter применять пробовал - пока не получилось, да и вроде бы это свойство только в Safari поддерживается.

Буду рад за любую помощь, спасибо.

Comment: фон статический? без скролла?

Comment: `blur` это топовая проблема всех времен , народов  и браузеров .

Comment: Да, фон статичный

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.background{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/sgXTCgKD/purple-sunset-wallpa.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
}

.background form{
    width: 326px;
    height: 134px;
    top: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.blur {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
     -moz-filter: blur(5px);
       -o-filter: blur(5px);
      -ms-filter: blur(5px);
          filter: blur(5px);
          background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/sgXTCgKD/purple-sunset-wallpa.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
}

.text {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
     -moz-filter: blur(0px);
       -o-filter: blur(0px);
      -ms-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
          }
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <form action="">
    
    <div  class="blur" ></div>
    
    <div class="text">
        Текст
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, действительно этот вариант работает, спасибо большое !!!